# Is there any method from where i can get the html element (h1 tag) value and render out to the server(express)?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, body-parser

I'm trying to get the value of html tag (h1) and send to the server with express. I've tried using body-parser, but it can be used only if the element is present in input tag. So, is their any method that i can get the value between h1 tag?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get text value from a h1 tag then you can follow up the code down below.

In your HTML

```
<h1 id="id"> My Value </h1>
```

Now in your javascript code :

```
let h1Value = document.getElementById('id').innerHTML;
```

Let me know if that works out for you :)

Comment: Thanks, but this is a frontend approach for getting data. I want backend method so that i can use it on my server.

Comment: @Sumit Your backend cant access your frontend DOM from backend unless site is dynamically generated from backend like with Ejs. Your question is not clear. From what I understood you might be submitting a form  in which you also want to include the h1 value. Instead of directly submitting the form call a function and include the heading value in it.

Comment: @kirangoud I'm not working with the form. here i want to get the element present in ejs template i.e h1

Comment: Dynamically generate h1 tag with a variable. you will have access to it.